# Does an Adobe AIR ActiveX Control exist?

Tags: windows, air, adobe, activex

I was wondering: does an AIR ActiveX Control exist? I want to load an SWF movie inside a Flash ActiveX controller, but the movie was created using Adobe Air and therefore it cannot load some of its dependencies.

I've seen an Air to .EXE wrapper somewhere around the internet, so I think it is possible somehow.

Any clues on this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Theo